# What does yellow bar indicates when running tests in IDEAL intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

In intellij IDEAL all tests passes but the bar of the tests is yellow. I am using TestNG. Does anybody know what does this mean ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that some tests were not executed by TestNG (no message received about completion for some of the tests). See if you can reproduce it in IDEA 12.

If the issue persists, contact support with the sample to reproduce and specify your TestNG version.

Comment: Why would this happen you might ask? In my situation, an `Exception` was being caught and `System.exit(1)` was being called. As an aside, when running via `maven-surefire-plugin` this situation was even worse - the test is aborted and the failure is not captured in the results.